# Unable to make Prediction on Test Data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, sklearn-pandas

```
#Linear Regression Model
from sklearn import linear_model
linear_model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
linear_model.fit(x_train, y_train)
print("Linear Model Coefficients:", linear_model.coef_)
print("Linear Model Intercepts:", linear_model.intercept_)
print("")
#Predicting Prices using the models
y_pred = linear_model.predict(x_test)
```

But this gives an output: **module 'sklearn.linear_model' has no attribute 'predict'**

Comment: That's not just an output, but an exception. Please post full traceback.

Comment: This is solved. The model variable name and the model name were similar which is why it is getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use other variable name instead of `linear_model`. The variable and function name are equal, resulting in the error you have.

Example code as follow.

```
from sklearn import linear_model
model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
print("Linear Model Coefficients:", model.coef_)
print("Linear Model Intercepts:", model.intercept_)
print("")
#Predicting Prices using the models
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Worked like Magic. Strange it has no problem accessing the coef_ and intercept_ objects but cannot call the function with that name.